# transitional mutation, repair mechanism

Tags: dna-damage

I have read an answer to a question about dna [repair during and after replication](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28015/repair-wrong-dna-pair-after-ending-replication).

But how is dna repaired if a deamination of of 5-methylcytosine happens? How does a repair mechanism identify which base was mutated (on '3 or on '5 strand, a C to T, or on the complementary strand an A to G)?

Comment: I don't have time for an answer right now, but you can look up very short patch repair for bacteria. For higher organisms where methyl-C occurs in CpG sites, repair enzymes can recognize the mutated strand by the presence of methylated CpG on the complementary strand.

Comment: [DNA Glycosylases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_glycosylase), like [UDG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uracil-DNA_glycosylase), and [hSMUG1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMUG1) contribute to specifically sniffing out instances of Uracil that occur in the DNA. Havent time for a full answer myself, but these are just a few resources.

Comment: Deamination of 5mC gives T, not U.

Comment: Yikes, that's embarrassing! Disregard my above comment unless you're curious!